# How to Use rbind and cbind on Single Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind, cbind

Sorry for the wrong question framing.
Iam a newbie,trying to learn R on my own.

I have a scenario like,

**t1_df**

```
id   name   address
1     x       india
2     y       usa
```

**t2_df**

```
id   name   address
3     a      india
4     b       usa
```

Now i tried to add extra column "msg" using data.frame
i.e

```
t1_df <- data.frame(t1_df,msg)
t2_df <- data.frame(t2_df,msg)
```

t1_df

```
  id   name   address   msg
  1     x       india   hi
  2     y       usa     hello
```

t2_df

```
id   name   address   msg
3     a      india     go
4     b       usa      bye
```

when i tried to do **rbind** it gives error as **col names are not matching because both df's having different col names**

When i tried to cbind on both df's into single dataframe is **t**, it included all the columns from both df's
i.e

**colnames(t)**

```
id   name   address   t1_msg   id   name   address   t2_msg
```

But i would like to get the dataframe as

```
id   name   address   t1_msg   t2_msg
  1     x       india   hi       NA
  2     y       usa     hello    NA
  3     a      india     NA      go
  4     b       usa      NA      bye
```

How can i get the output as i have mentioned above.

Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance
Mohan.V

Comment: Based on the example data showed, the column names are matching.  Do you have any leading/lagging spaces in the column names. Use `rbindlist` from `data.table` i.e. `rbindlist(list(t1_df, t2_df))`

Comment: thanks for the reply akrun,                                                                             i tried what you have suggested but it giving me only the t1_msg from t1_df, as i have mentioned i need to get 2 diff columns as t1_msg and t2_msg in a single data frame of

Comment: Then, change the column names as `t1_msg` and `t2_msg` and use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` i.e. `names(t1_df)[4] <- "t1_msg"; names(t2_df)[4] <- "t2_msg"; bind_rows(t1_df, t2_df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use merge. Example:

recreating your dataframes:

```
t1_df<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,     "x",      "india",
                              2,     "y",       "usa"), ncol= 3, nrow =2, byrow= T)
                     )
names(t1_df) <- c("id","name","address")

t2_df<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(3,     "a",      "india",
4,     "b",       "usa"), ncol= 3, nrow =2, byrow= T))
names(t2_df) <- c("id","name","address")
```

Add msg variables. To use merge give both variables a slightly different name (in your case t1_msg and t2_msg)

```
t1_df$t1_msg <- c("hi","hello")
t2_df$t2_msg <- c("go","bye")
```

Then use merge to merge the dataframes. Setting all = TRUE will append rows that have no exact match in the other dataframe.

```
merge(t1_df,t2_df,all = TRUE)
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
  id name address t1_msg t2_msg
1  1    x   india     hi   <NA>
2  2    y     usa  hello   <NA>
3  3    a   india   <NA>     go
4  4    b     usa   <NA>    bye
```